# Group by SUBSTR

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, left-join, substr

Can someone explain to me why the following code works with no errors:

```
SELECT t1.column1,
       t1.column2,
       t1.column3,
       ctot as Cost,
       (ctot * t1.qty) as FinalCost
FROM Table1 t1

LEFT JOIN (SELECT column1,
                  column2,
                  column3,
                  column4,
             MAX(DateCol),
             AVG(CostCol) KEEP(DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY t2.DateCol) as ctot
FROM Table2 t2
GROUP BY column1, column2, SUBSTR(column3, 1, 5), column4) t2
     ON t2.column1 = t1.column1
     AND t2.column2 = t1.column2
     AND t2.column4 = t1.column4
     AND SUBSTR(t1.column3, 1, 5) = SUBSTR(t2.column3, 1, 5)
     WHERE t1.ID1 = '500'
     AND t1.ID2 != '50'
```

While this code will produce error `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`:

```
SELECT t1.column1,
       t1.column2,
       t1.column3,
       ctot as Cost,
       (ctot * t1.qty) as FinalCost
FROM Table1 t1

LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.column1 = t2.column1
   AND t1.column2 = t2.column2

LEFT JOIN (SELECT IdCol as points, column3 FROM Table3) t3
    ON t2.column3 = t3.column3

LEFT JOIN (SELECT column1,
                  column3,
             MAX(DateCol),
             AVG(CostCol) KEEP(DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY t4.DateCol) as ctot
FROM Table4 t4
GROUP BY column1, SUBSTR(column3, 1, 5)) t4
    ON t4.column1 = points
   AND SUBSTR(t4.column3, 1, 5) = SUBSTR(t1.column3, 1, 5)
 WHERE t1.ID1 = '500'
   AND t1.ID2 != '50'
```

My editor highlights `column3` in my final join statement as the cause of the error, and replacing `SUBSTR(column3, 1, 5)` with `column3` in the `GROUP BY` statement fixes this error. But why is the error being thrown in the second example but not the first? Does it have to do with the multiple join statements?

Comment: Can you please use `/*+ NO_QUERY_TRANSFORMATION */` in your first query, outer select statement and see the result?

Comment: Please **edit your question** and include data for each of the tables used in your query which allows the problem to be reproduced. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that your first query looks exactly as you showed? I [tried to reproduce it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=28e944e8d2c9b34d0277bde19506415a) as close as possbile and I always got `ORA-00979`. Because Your inner query alone throws it. So can you reproduce it in dbfiddle? Maybe it is something with Oracle version? Anyway how could Oracle group by substr and show full strings in select list? It should throw an error and throws it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `LEFT JOIN` in main select, thats mean Oracle is using SQL92. So you must use in `GROUP BY` clausule exat part of `SELECT` projection.

e.i. use this in subselect:

```
SELECT column1,
    column2,
    SUBSTR(column3, 1, 5) as column3, -- column3 after substr()
    column4,
    MAX(DateCol),
    AVG(CostCol) KEEP(DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY t2.DateCol) AS ctot
FROM Table2 t2
GROUP BY column1, column2, SUBSTR(column3, 1, 5), column4
```

Comment: Indeed this does work. I'm not sure why the first query wasn't resulting in an error in my compiler but I think it's safer to always use this format to avoid conflicts in other compilers

Answer (score -1):

extra `)` at the end of the statement...

should just be

```
SELECT
  t1.column1,
  t1.column2,
  t1.column3,
  ctot AS Cost,
  (ctot * t1.qty) AS FinalCost
FROM Table1 t1

LEFT JOIN (SELECT
  column1,
  column2,
  column3,
  column4,
  MAX(DateCol),
  AVG(CostCol) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY t2.DateCol) AS ctot
FROM Table2 t2
GROUP BY column1,
         column2,
         SUBSTR(column3, 1, 5),
         column4) t2

  ON t2.column1 = t1.column1
  AND t2.column2 = t1.column2
  AND t2.column4 = t1.column4
  AND SUBSTR(t1.column3, 1, 5) = SUBSTR(t2.column3, 1, 5)
WHERE t1.ID1 = '500'
AND t1.ID2 != '50'
```